# Error when pulling from repository: unable to create file

Tags: windows, git, macos

I'm trying to push changes from my local macbook to a remote desktop server that exists on a computer at my school. The computer runs windows and I'm using git bash to try and coordinate my code.

When I push up from my macbook to the remote desktop and try to pull the changes down I get an error:

> unable to create file  (File exists)

What can I do to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

You probably added and pushed a file on your laptop that already exists on the server but not versioned yet. To avoid data loss git won't pull the versioned file to overwrite the unversioned one on the server. Check the status to see what unversioned files you have then either move those away or stash them.

If you want to stash them, use -u to stash unversioned files.